# Make sure 0 and comma stay in the variable without making it a string? PHP

Tags: php, html

For my internship I have to make sure I can filter numbers out of a piece of string inside of an Array (being: .nl per month: 0,83, etc).

For that I used the following code: `$nlMonth = (int) filter_var($fileLines[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);`

The result I get is 83, while it needs to be 0,83. Does anyone know any solution to this?

Comment: `0,83` (or `0.83`) isn't an integer?

Comment: Oh of course, I'll try to search for a different way to do this

Comment: `(float)str_replace(',', '.', $fileLines[1])`…?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
$nlMonth = filter_var('10.83', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

This output 10.83. If you want to change '.' to ',' then you can use str_replace with floatval() function.

Comment: thanks, it might work if it were a set number, but the problem for it is that it can be a number which could change over time, so I can't use an already set number for this

Answer (score -2):

Try it
echo mb_substr($string, 0, -1);

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Would this work for all kinds of strings?